# One Facebook app associated with multiple iOS apps

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad

My app is using iOS's native Facebook login to authenticate users. I have a Facebook app created for this. I noticed that I can provide multiple comma separated bundle ids there to share the same Facebook app with multiple iOS apps. My question is is there any limit on the number of bundle ids I can provide there ?

I am not sure why there is no mention of support of multiple bundle ids in FB's official documentation here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share-appid-across-multiple-apps-ios-sdk/

I know for fast app switching (with Safari or FB native app) a unique custom url is required but If I want to go with iOS's native authentication only (when user has FB setup in settings), is it safe to go with providing multiple bundle ids in the same FB app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We provided comma separated bundle ids of more than 200 iOS apps to the same Facebook App and Facebook integration is working fine in all iOS apps.

Comment: This is an old thread, but how is that working for you? We have 50 apps and want to use the same Facebook  Login APP for them all. Our tests in the first 2 seem to work fine. Have you run into any problems in utilizing one FB login app with your 200+ ios apps?

Comment: Did you put a value in the iPhone Store ID and iPad Store ID fields?

Comment: It use to work, now we are no longer using that app. I remember putting custom url suffix field.

Comment: It seemed like it would work if you didn't need to rely on facebook having to launch your app. However, once I delved into the android version, it doens't seem to have a way of adding multiple packages. So it's moot for me.

Comment: It should work if you add custom url suffix in FB app dashboard and code, no?

Comment: The FB app config settings page has an optional URL Scheme Suffix, but it appears to be iOS only. THe android config area has package name, class name and key hashes. It appears to me that I must have a separate FB login app for each android application, because FB asks for the package name, and only allows 1. My apps will have an iOS and Android version which I need FB login for.

Comment: @msk How would I go about tracking Facebook Ad Installs? I have three apps int he App Store which use the same Facebook id; login works like a charm, but I can only track app installs on the app with the App Store iPhone ID.

Comment: @HeavenlyManBR I can't refresh my memory now, this is very old problem.

Comment: For anyone looking for the answer for this, you'll need to create separate Facebook Apps to track app installs. This is not possible using the same Facebook App and multiple bundle ids.