# Facebook login app - multiple Bundle IDs -- Do I need to specify 'iPhone Store ID' and what is it used for?

Tags: ios, facebook

I am planning on using my Facebook login app in multiple IOS app implementations. I am producing many apps which will all use the same Facebook login API app.

Assuming that this is an OK approach (I see that I can use multiple bundle id's which is what gave me the idea in the first place), what should I put in the 'iPhone Store ID'? Or do I even need to?

I guess I am not sure what the purpose is of storing the iPhone Store ID. I only use FB for logging in and don't utilize in-app purchases.

Comment: pls refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7746019/native-ios-app-what-do-i-put-in-facebooks-developer-iphone-app-store-id-unde

Comment: you cannot make use of iphone store ID. You should find another approach.

Comment: You will find many problems if you use the same Facebook App ID for many apps

Comment: Thanks for the notes, but can you clarify? I am not sure why the APP Store ID is pertinent. I have been able to test a few apps with this method and they work fine and I didn't put anything in the iPhone Store ID field. I use the FB login app only for login, and never (I think) will Facebook need to redirect a user to my app download page. I see that FB allows for multiple IOS app bundle IDs to be specified, so it seems like they support it. I can go and create a separate FB login for each one but it seems superfluous (but then again I am a bit of a newbie).

Comment: I found this post saying they've used 200+ ios apps tied to a single FB login. I asked them how it's working.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886926/one-facebook-app-associated-with-multiple-ios-apps

Comment: That is a great question. Although it seems to work fine for login purposes, I wonder if it will work for Ads. We have three iOS apps with the same FB ID and I can only see installs from one app in Ads reporting.